# Scroll to a specific part of a UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextview

In the Swift app I'm creating, the user can type some text into a text view and then search for a specific string within it, just like in Pages (and numerous others).

I have the `index` of the character they are searching for as an Integer (i.e., they are on the third instance of "hello" in the massive text block they typed in, and I know that's the 779th letter of the text view) and I am trying to automatically scroll the text view to the string they're on, so that it pops out (like it would in Pages).

I am trying to jump to the applicable string with this command:

```
self.textview.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(index, 0))
```

but it never jumps to the right place (sometimes too far down, sometimes way too far up), often depending on screen size, so I know that `index` doesn't belong right there.

**How can I correctly allow the user to jump to a specific string in a text view, by making the text view scroll to a certain character?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get string, which is before index 779, and then calculate the height of this string and then scroll to this point.

```
let string = textView.text.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: textView.text.startIndex, end: textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(779)))// your <779 string
let size = string.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:yourFont])
let point = CGPointMake(0, size.height)
scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated:true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One issue: on the first line of that, I'm getting `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<Index>' with an argument list of type '(start: Index, end: String.CharacterView.Index)'`. I should note I'm using Swift 3.

Comment: @JohnRamos just try literal then, instead of Range<String.Index> use something like textView.text.startIndex..<textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(779)

Comment: There's no `advancedBy` function in Swift 3!!

Comment: @JohnRamos try Collection.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 779)

Comment: Ok, I figured out my issues and will edit your code, but it crashes every once in a while, when I type in more letters to search. The index goes out of range.

Comment: @JohnRamos provide your search code please. And sorry, I didn't have a chance to look at swift 3, but my code should've gave you an idea.

Comment: In coordination with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39359207/5700898) your code totally works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't understand how this could possibly work, sizeWithAttributes is returning the size of the string without taking into account the text view it is printed in, meaning the height will not take into account word wrap. So how could it possibly return a height that you can use to scroll to the correct place in the textview, which is probably wrapping the lines in places.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer doesn't seem to work anymore (Jan 2021). But there is a simpler way now:

```
// Range specific to the question, any other works
let rangeStart = textView.text.startIndex
let rangeEnd = textView.text.index(rangeStart, offsetBy: 779)
let range = rangeStart..<rangeEnd

// Convert to NSRange
let nsrange = NSRange(range, in: textView.text)

// ... and scroll
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(nsrange)
```